# Row-wise iteration like apply with purrr

Tags: r, apply, purrr

How do I achieve row-wise iteration using purrr::map?

Here's how I'd do it with a standard row-wise apply.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20, c = 21:30)

lst_result <- apply(df, 1, function(x){
            var1 <- (x[['a']] + x[['b']])
            var2 <- x[['c']]/2
            return(data.frame(var1 = var1, var2 = var2))
          })
```

However, this is not too elegant, and I would rather do it with purrr.  May (or may not) be faster, too.

Answer (score 71):

You can use `pmap` for row-wise iteration.  The columns are used as the arguments of whatever function you are using. In your example you would have a three-argument function.

For example, here is `pmap` using an anonymous function for the work you are doing. The columns are passed to the function in the order they are in the dataset.

```
pmap(df, function(a, b, c) {
     data.frame(var1 = a + b,
                var2 = c/2) 
     }  )
```

You can use the *purrr* tilde "short-hand" for an anonymous function by referring to the columns in order with numbers preceded by two dots.

```
pmap(df, ~data.frame(var1 = ..1 + ..2,
                var2 = ..3/2)  )
```

If you want to get these particular results as a data.frame instead of a list, you can use `pmap_dfr`.

Comment: In the first example, what do I do if the df has 100 columns and I only want to manipulate the 90th one?  I understand I can refer to it by index number, but I would like to refer to it by name.

Comment: @matsuo_basho If you only want to use a single column, other tools might be more appropriate (e.g., `dplyr::mutate`).  However, the documentation for `pmap` points out that you can always use `...` to "absorb unused components of input [the] list".  So if the column of interest was named "c", something like `pmap(df, function(c, ...) {data.frame(var1 = c/2) })` would work.

Comment: what is `...` used for?

Comment: @AlvaroMorales It takes all of the rest of the column names so you don't need to refer to every single column name in `pmap()`. There is an example in the documentation `Examples` section of the **map** family of functions that you might find useful!

Answer (score 10):

Note that you're using only vectorized operations in your example so you could very well do :

```
df %>% dplyr::transmute(var1 = a+b,var2 = c/2)
```

(or in base R: `transform(df,var1 = a+b,var2 = c/2)[4:5]`)

If you use non vectorized functions such as median you can use `pmap` as in @aosmith 's answer, or use `dplyr::rowwise`.

`rowwise` is slower and the package maintainers advise to use the `map` family instead, but it's arguably easier on the eye than `pmap` in some cases. I personally still use it when speed isn't an issue:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% transmute(var3 = pmap(.,~median(c(..1,..2,..3))))
df %>% rowwise %>% transmute(var3 = median(c(a,b,c)))
```

(to go back to a strict unnamed list output : `res %>% split(seq(nrow(.))) %>% unname`)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `pmap` and the `...` in combination which for me is the best solution because I dont need to specify the parameters.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20, c = 21:30)

lst_result <- df %>%
   pmap(function(...) {
       x <- tibble(...)
      return(tibble(var1 = x$a + x$b, var2 = x$c/2))
   })
```

Answer (score 6):

You are free to always make a wrapper around a function you "like".

```
rmap <- function (.x, .f, ...) {
    if(is.null(dim(.x))) stop("dim(X) must have a positive length")
    .x <- t(.x) %>% as.data.frame(.,stringsAsFactors=F)
    purrr::map(.x=.x,.f=.f,...)
}
```

apply the new function `rmap` (**r**owwise**map**)

```
rmap(df1,~{
    var1 <- (.x[[1]] + .x[[2]])
    var2 <- .x[[3]]/2
    return(data.frame(var1 = var1, var2 = var2))
    })
```

Additional Info: (eval from top to bottom)

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=1:3,c=1:3)
m   <- matrix(1:9,ncol=3)

apply(df1,1,sum)
rmap(df1,sum)

apply(m,1,sum)
rmap(m,sum)

apply(1:10,1,sum)  # intentionally throws an error
rmap(1:10,sum)     # intentionally throws an error
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `group_nest()` to access each row as a one-row-tibble:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20, c = 21:30)

df %>% 
    group_nest(row_number()) %>% 
    pull(data) %>% 
    map(function(x) transmute(x,
                                 var1 = a + b,
                                 var2 = c/2))
```

Answer (score 2):

I like (and upvoted) the group_nest answer by @rasmus-larsen, but I think it's cleaner to use group_by and group_map:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20, c = 21:30)
lst_result <- df %>% 
  group_by(row_number()) %>%
  group_map(function(x, i) {
    x %>% transmute(
      var1 = a + b,
      var2 = c/2
    )
  })
```

But, why not simply do the following? It would be faster.

```
transmute(df, var1 = a + b, var2 = c/2)
```